# delay not working in this case

Tags: jquery

I have one div, id = "upload_msg".

I want to show this up after 5 seconds on document.ready

Once it's shown up, I want to add text (say "File Uploaded") and apply a css class

I have wrote following code

```
jQuery("#upload_msg").delay(5000).addClass('updated').text('File Uploaded');
```

But I don't see any delay, can someone help me out

Comment: are you sure you don't want some way of determining when the file has finished uploading?

Comment: I have already achieved way to determine when file is uploaded completely

Comment: fair enough, I don't quite get why you would tell your user 5 seconds later but to each their own ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#upload_msg").addClass('updated').text('File Uploaded');
},5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.delay()` only works with things in a queue, which normally means effects and animations. However, you can force anything you want into a queue, with the aptly-named [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

```
jQuery("#upload_msg").delay(5000).queue(function () {
    $(this).addClass('updated').text('File Uploaded');
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQueryUI if you're going to use `addClass` as an effect.

It's easier to use `setTimeout` to do your bidding:

```
setTimeout( function(){
  $('#upload_msg').addClass('updated').text('File Uploaded');
}, 5000);
```